# TypeError: Cannot read property 'minify' of undefined in Nuxt.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

When im generating nuxt app using "npm run generate" or "npm run build" it throws TypeError: Cannot read property 'minify' of undefined
How to fix this

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'minify' of undefined              
    at minify (C:\Users\hiraz\webdev\vue\nuxt\demo\cms-demo002\node
js:175:23)                                                         
    at module.exports (C:\Users\hiraz\webdev\vue\nuxt\demo\cms-demo
\worker.js:13:40)                                                  
    at handle (C:\Users\hiraz\webdev\vue\nuxt\demo\cms-demo002\node
8)                                                                 
    at process.<anonymous> (C:\Users\hiraz\webdev\vue\nuxt\demo\cms
\index.js:51:3)                                                    
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)                                  
    at process.emit (events.js:214:7)                              
    at emit (internal/child_process.js:762:12)                     
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:142:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:181:9)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was a bug in a dependency called terser v3.16 released yesterday causing this problem.

Fix it by:

```
npm i terser@3.14
```

Comment: This is the GH issue, for reference: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/terser-webpack-plugin/issues/66